Cannot find Youtube channel membership API
I have a creator account (saiupigliamosche) with partnership enabled.
I'm trying to enable the youtube channel membership API, but I cannot find it in the google cloud console.
enter image description here
I am stuck, I need help.
Thanks
I tried also to use API via google developers website (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list?hl=it&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22managedByMe%22%3Atrue%7D)
but I keep getting the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The channel does not have Channel Memberships enabled.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The channel does not have Channel Memberships enabled.",
        "domain": "youtube.member",
        "reason": "channelMembershipsNotEnabled"
      }
    ]
  }
}



If I had to guess, I'd say the message "The channel does not have Channel Memberships enabled." is trying to tell you that the Youtube channel in question does not have memberships enabled.

That would be a good guess, and it was also what we (I am developing the script with Riccardo) originally thought, but the channel in question (https://www.youtube.com/@saiupigliamosche) is anabled, and we even contacted YouTube support, which confirmed this. They told us this is an API related issue and that we should open a thread on StackOVerflow, as detailed here (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support)
